# How to check if the response Body has a string for a nested JSON in POSTMAN

Tags: json, postman

To check if the Respondy Body has a string, I can use this:

```
tests["Body matches string"] = responseBody.has("string_you_want_to_search");
```

But I have a responseBody like this:

```
{  
 "total": 20000,
 "amount": {
   "total": 10000,
   "fees": 0,
   "refunds": 0,
   "liquid": 10000,
   "currency": "BRL"
 },
}
```

How can I check the field amount.total?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [postman jetpacks - testing for nested data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161571/postman-jetpacks-testing-for-nested-data)

Comment: You can use `JSON.parse(responseBody)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dot operator to test to access the nested value:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["10000"] = data.amount.liquid === "10000";
tests["BRL"] = data.amount.currency === "BRL";
```

Hope it helps!